# How do i mock JWT.decode?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am using this library in my Spring boot application.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
  <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

How do I do my unit test for `DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(accessToken);`?

I could just pass in an actual token in but that is not the correct way to do it.

I have this JwtAuthenticationFilter in my Spring Boot app.

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Value("${clientid}")
    private String clientid;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException, InvalidRoleException {

        getJwtFromRequest(request, response, filterChain);
    }

    private void getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

            String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");

            if (!StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) || !bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                throw new AccessTokenMissingException("No access token found in request headers.");
            }

            try {
                String accessToken = bearerToken.substring(7);

                // this will also throw error when unable to reach auth server
                ResponseEntity<String> result = authenticationService.getUserInfo(accessToken);

                // Invalid access token
                if (!result.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                    throw new InvalidAccessTokenException("Invalid access token.");
                }

                DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(accessToken);

                String username = jwt.getClaim("preferred_username").asString();
                Map<String, Object> resources = jwt.getClaim("resource_access").asMap();

                Object roles = ((Map<String, Object>) resources.get(clientid)).get("roles");

                List<String> rolesList = (ArrayList<String>)roles;

                UserInfo user = new UserInfo();
                user.setUsername(username);
                user.setRole(rolesList);

                // Step 3: Set username to security context
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        user.getUsername(), null, AuthUtil.getAuthRole(user.getRole()));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

            } catch (HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized | JWTDecodeException e) {
                throw new InvalidAccessTokenException("Invalid access token.");
            }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different strategies/options you can use, all will work:

1. Don't mock the JWT.decode at all, treat it as a utility method that should run within the test. The intuition behind it, what if your class was using `Math.max(a,b)` code or, or some date time manipulation like `DateTime.of(...)` would you mock it in the test? Probably not... Although in this case you will probably have to work with really decodable tokens in the test
2. Use PowerMockito to mock the static call (I don't really recommend this way, but it will do the job if you don't want to change the code).
3. Do a refactoring extracting the decode functionality to the interface and use it as a dependency in the filter:

```
public interface JWTDecoder {
   DecodedJWT decode(String token); // I assume its string for simplicity
}

@Component
public class StdJWTDecoder implements JWTDecoder {
   public DecodedJWT decode(String token) {
       return JWT.decode(tokent);
}

public class JwtAuthenticationFilter ... {
   private final JWTDecoder jwtDecoder;

   public JwtAuthenticationFilter(JWTDecoder jwtDecoder) {
       this.jwtDecoder = jwtDecoder;
   }

    ....
   private void getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
     response, FilterChain filterChain)  {
      ...
      // instead of:
      DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(accessToken);  
      // use this:
      DecodedJWT jwt = jwtDecoder.decode(accessToken);
      ...
   }

}
```

With this approach you can mock the `JwtDecoder` with mockito easily

Comment: Thanks. i was wondering how do I even mock the result of this `DecodedJWT` class

Comment: `public interface JWTDecoder {
    String getEmail(String token) throws JWTDecodeException;
}`

`@Component
public class StandardJWTDecoder implements JWTDecoder  {

    public String getEmail(String token) throws JWTDecodeException {
        return JWT.decode(token).getClaim("email").asString();
    }
}`


Mockito.when(jwtDecoder.getEmail(any())).thenReturn("userName@abc.com");


i want the mock for email.  i've done that by creating a method for that.